# Orientation change but view's frame doesn't work correctly in iOS

Tags: ios

I have a custom container view controller(red background color). Front view controller added as child view controller. Container view controller supports `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait`, child view controller supports all orientations. When rotate the simulator , views do not position correctly.

Here is the view hierarchy.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting child controller view's `autoresizingMask` to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`.